# Configurable products showing out of stock

Tags: magento2, stock, configurable-product

Some of my Configurable products are showing out-of-stock, but child SKU's having quantities.

Simple produts are showing IN-stock it's working fine.

Please let me know what is the reason of Configurable products are showing out-of-stock.